# Angularjs active state not applying on clicked button

Tags: angularjs

I have this very simple app with a few buttons. When the button is clicked the active css should be applied. It is not working for me for some reason,

controller:

```
'use strict';
angular
    .module('myApp')
    .controller('summaryCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope){


            $scope.buttons=[
                {time:'1 Hour'},
                {time:'2 Hours'},
                {time:'24 Hours'},
                {time:'48 Hours'},
                {time:'1 Week'},
                {time:'1 Month'}
            ];

        $scope.selected = $scope.buttons[0];

        $scope.select= function(item) {
            $scope.selected = item;
        };

        $scope.isActive = function(item) {
            return $scope.selected === item;
        };

    }]);
```

navigation:

```
<div ng-controller="summaryCtrl">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="button in buttons" id="{{ button.time }}"   ng-click="selectButton($index)" ng-class="{active: $index===selectedButton}">{{ button.time }}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/0WxnRVwaHwCBGM6wXNtS?p=preview

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call the `selectButton` method in your `ng-click` directive but this method doesn't exist in your `$scope`. You named it `select()`. Also, the property `selectedButton` you use in your `ng-class` directive is not the one containing the selected button. It's simply `selected` like you assign it in your `$scope.select()` method.

Try like this:

```
<div ng-controller="summaryCtrl">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="button in buttons" id="{{ button.time }}" ng-click="select($index)" ng-class="{active: $index === selected}">{{ button.time }}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: oh cool, many thanks. how do I make the first button already selected when the page is loaded?

Comment: Just assign the `$scope.selected` variable to `0`.